# How is it that my image will only flip once?

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, image-rotation, flip

4 images are displayed and it's suppose to flip the image horizontally on click and swap image with another by using the arrow indicator. The image swap is working, but the image will only flip once.

Below is my code, how is it not possible to flip the image multiple times?

I've tried several thing and I can't seem to get it working.. HELP!

```
<body>
    <h1>My Images Gallery</h1>


    <div class="polaroid">
        <img src="winter.jpg" alt="Winter view" style="width:100%">
        <div class="container">
            <p>Make the image just like this by clicking and moving the tiles</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="a">
                <img id="imga" src="right-top.jpg" alt="Winter view" onclick="flip('imga')">
                <div id="texta">Right top tile</div>
            </td>
            <td id="pijlTop" class="pijl">
                <span onclick="swap('a', 'b')">&#8644</span>
            </td>
            <td id="b">
                <div>
                    <img id="imgb" src="left-top.jpg" alt="Winter view" onclick="flip('imgb')">
                </div>
                <div id="textb">Left top tile</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="pijlLeft" class="pijl">
                <span onclick="swap('a', 'c')">&#8645</span>
            </td>
            <td/>
            <td id="pijlRight" class="pijl">
                <span onclick="swap('b', 'd')">&#8645</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c">
                <div>
                    <img id="imgc" src="right-down.jpg" alt="Winter view" onclick="flip('imgc')">
                </div>
                <div id="textc">Right bottom tile</div>
            </td>
            <td id="pijlBottom" class="pijl">
                <span onclick="swap('c', 'd')">&#8644</span>
            </td>
            <td id="d">
                <img id="imgd" src="left-down.jpg" alt="Winter view" onclick="flip('imgd')">
                <div id="textd">Left bottom tile</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        function flip(a) {
            var img = document.getElementById(a);
            if (img.style === 'img'){ 
            img.style = "transform:rotate(180deg);";
            }
            else {
                img.style = "transform:rotate(180deg);";
            }
        }

        function swap(a, b) {
            var atext = document.getElementById("text" + a).innerHTML;
            var btext = document.getElementById("text" + b).innerHTML;
            var aimg = document.getElementById("img" + a).src;
            var bimg = document.getElementById("img" + b).src;

            document.getElementById("text" + a).innerHTML = btext;
            document.getElementById("text" + b).innerHTML = atext;
            document.getElementById("img" + a).src = bimg;
            document.getElementById("img" + b).src = aimg;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The transformation isn't cumulative, so if you apply `transform:rotate(180deg)` you get an upside-down image, and then if you apply `transform:rotate(180deg)` again you get...the same upside-down image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing this line

```
else {
    img.style = "transform:rotate(0deg);";
}
```

That should fix it!

Comment: Also did the trick with some minor changes, nice to have more options!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this snippet!

```js
$('.container').click(function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.active {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`transform:rotate(180deg)` always sets rotation **relative to the original image**. This is why your code rotates an image only once. If you want to flip the image again you should check if it is flipped and if so, set it back to `transform:rotate(0deg)`. Here is plain javascript implementation since I noticed you are not using jQuery.

HTML:

```
function flip(a) {
  var img = document.getElementById(a);
  if(img.classList.contains('flipped')){
    img.classList.remove('flipped');
  } else {
    img.classList.add('flipped');
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.flipped {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Award-winning [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afqvyy0h/).

Comment: @MariaT you should upvote answers that you found helpful and accept one that solves your problem best.